# Show that $x^5-x^2-4=0$ has at least one real root

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Proof

Since $x^5-x^2-4=0$ is a polynomial it is continuous on any interval [a,b] such that a,b are real numbers

say:
$f(a)= x$ such that $x<0$

$f(b)=z$ such that $z>0$

$k=0$

Since k is between $x$ and $z$ by the intermediate value theorem it follows that there is a number $c$ such that $f(c)=c^5-c^2-4=0$

Comment: What is $k$?  You are on the right track. There are easy choices for $a,b$ and you will be done.

Comment: The idea is fine. You should explicitly provide $a$ and $b$ however.

Comment: $a=0$ and $b=2$ already works.

Comment: so say a=-3 and b=3?

Comment: The sign rule of Descartes shows even more, namely that there is exactly one positive root.

Comment: @K.Gibson:  yes, those work fine.  I would have started with $a=0$ because it required less computation.

Comment: Generalization : Every polynomial in $\mathbb R[X]$ with an odd degree has at least one real root.

Comment: How do you know that f (a)<0 exists?  How do you know f (b) >0 exists.  I rather think that's the entire point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: What is $x \to \infty$? What is $x \to -\infty$. What does the intermediate value theroem say? For the limits you can use $f(x)=x^5(1-1/x^3-4/x^5)$

Comment: I have no idea what it says but that some interesting questions. well the limit would be infinity for the first one as you would get infinity to the power of 5 times (1-0-0). which is infinity times a number?

Comment: The function will go to $+ \infty$ and $-\infty$. So because $f(x)$ is continous it will take any value from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ (intermediate value theorem), hence it will be $0$ somewhere, which implies the existence of at least one real root. In general any polynomial of odd order will have at least one real root.

Answer (score 2):

Here is maybe an other interesting proof.

If $c$ is a complex root, then $\overline{c}$ is also a complex root. It follows from the fact that $$P(\overline{c}) =\overline{\overline{P}(c)}=\overline{P(c)}=0,$$ since your polynomial $P$ has real coefficients. Hence the number of complex (non real) roots is always even.

Here because the degree of your polynomial is odd, you have at least one real root. (Because you can only have $0,2$ or $4$ complex non real roots, but not $5$.)

This can be easily generalized : if $P$ is a polynomial with odd degree and with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$, then it has at least one real root.

Answer (score 0):

This particular problem
is a special case
of this theorem:

A polynomial
$p(x)
=\sum_{k=0}^d a_k x^k
$
with $a_d > 0$
and
$a_0 < 0
$
has a positive real root.

Proof:

$p(0) = a_0
< 0$
and,
for large enough $x$,
$p(x) > 0$
(because $a_d > 0$).

By the intermediate value theorem,
$p$ has a positive root.